# How will I access a field of a list<class> while using varStatus in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have two arraylists and would like to print them in a tabular format. I tried the following and getting an exception that reads - **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ss"**

JAVA code

```
List<Territory> terrList = new ArrayList<Territory>(); 
List<ProspCount> prospCountList = new ArrayList<ProspCount>();
model.put("terrList",terrList);     
model.put("prospCountList",prospCountList );
```

structure of Territory class

```
String terr;
```

structure of ProspCount class

```
private Integer taggedCount;
private Integer ss;
private Integer nss;
private Integer ssA;
```

JSP code:

```
 <c:forEach items="${model.terrList}" var="terr" varStatus = "loop">
<tr>
   <td>${terr}</td>
     <td> ${model.prospCountList.ss[loop.index]} </td>
     <td> ${model.prospCountList.nss[loop.index]} </td>
      .....
      .....
</tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over the `terrList` member, not the `propsCountList` member. Use `${model.propsCountList[loop.index].ss`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with drvdijk answer. As `model.prospCountList.ss` is not a list/array, there is no point trying to access an index of this list/array.

I'll advice you to format properly the content you want to iterate over directly in your Java code.

```
List<Territory> terrList = new ArrayList<Territory>(); 
List<ProspCount> prospCountList = new ArrayList<ProspCount>();
```

Can't you creat something like this?

```
List<TerritoryWithProspCount> terrList = new ArrayList<TerritoryWithProspCount>();
```

This will make the JSP code a lot more readable.